# In metric space, show if a set is open, then its complement is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I am writing down a sketch of the proof to the following problem in words and would appreciate your 2cent!

Given an arbitrary metric space $(X,δ)$, show that if a set $Y \subset X$ is open, then its complement is closed.

**Sketch of the proof (in words):**

(1) Given the arbitrary metric space, suppose $Y\subset X$ is open.

(2) Suppose $Y^c$, the complement of $Y$, is not closed.

(3) By (2), there exists a limit point of $Y^c$ that is not contained in $Y^c$. Denote this point $y^*$.

(4) $y^*$ is in $Y$, and there exists a sequence in $Y^c$ that converges to $y^*$.

(5) By (4), $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists y_c\in Y^c$, $y_c\in B_\epsilon(y^*)$.

(6) But we assumed Y is open.

This is a contradiction. It must be that $Y^c$ is closed. QED.

Comment: A closed set is *by definition* the complement of an open set. There's nothing to prove.

Comment: It is a lemma not a definition.

Comment: what is your definition of closed? containing every limit points?

Comment: I guess, $A$ is open if $\forall a\in A\,\exists\epsilon>0: B_\epsilon(a)\subseteq A$, and $B$ is closed if all its limit points belong to $B$.

Comment: In my very first analysis class, we defined an open set as one in which every point is an interior point and a closed set in which every boundary point is in the set.

Comment: Simple prose beats elaborate arguments and too much notation, any day.:)  Consider the following (might want to sketch an illustration):

Say you have a sequence $x_{n}$ in $Y^{c}$ that converges to $x$.  If $x$ were in $Y$, then it would have an open neighborhood $U \subset Y$.  Because of the convergence, this neighborhood contains all but finitely many of the $x_{n}$'s, but then the sequence could not be contained in $Y^{c}$.

Comment: Thanks guys! This problem is actually IFF lemma as I understand it. It is not a definition because in general topological spaces, without completeness, open iff complement closed would not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far so good. 
Maybe you should elaborate why (5) contradicts $Y$ being open.

Otherwise, if done, I also suggest to translate the same to a direct proof: 
We want to prove that $Y^\complement$ is closed, so take an arbitrary limit point $y^*$ of $Y^\complement$, and try to deduce that $y^*\notin Y$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove the "A set is closed if and only if its complement is open" without using the notion of metricspace ?

Comment: Yes, moreover in general topological space, it is already *defined* so.